# Handling a lot of concurrent connections in Python 3 asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

Iam trying to improve the performance of my application. It is a Python3.6 asyncio.Protocol based TCP server (SSL wrapped) handling a lot of requests.

It works fine and the performance is acceptable when only one connection is active, but as soon as another connection is opened, the client part of the application slows down. This is really noticeable once there are 10-15 client connection.

Is there a way to properly handle requests in parallel or should I resort to running multiple server instances?

/edit Added code

**main**.py

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import package.server
    server = package.server.TCPServer()
    server.join()
```

package.server

```py
import multiprocessing, asyncio, uvloop
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(uvloop.EventLoopPolicy())

from package.connection import Connection

class TCPServer(multiprocessing.Process):
    name = 'tcpserver'
    def __init__(self, discord_queue=None):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True

        # some setup in here

        self.start()

    def run(self):
        loop = uvloop.new_event_loop()
        self.loop = loop

        # db setup, etc

        server = loop.create_server(Connection, HOST, PORT, ssl=SSL_CONTEXT)
        loop.run_until_complete(server)
        loop.run_forever()
```

package.connection

```py
import asyncio, hashlib, os

from time import sleep, time as timestamp

class Connection(asyncio.Protocol):
    connections = {}

    def setup(self, peer):
        self.peer = peer

        self.ip, self.port = self.peer[0], self.peer[1]
        self.buffer = []

    @property
    def connection_id(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_connection_id'):
            self._connection_id = hashlib.md5('{}{}{}'.format(self.ip, self.port, timestamp()).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        return self._connection_id

    def connection_lost(self, exception):
        del Connection.connections[self.connection_id]

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        self.setup(transport.get_extra_info('peername'))
        Connection.connections[self.connection_id] = self

    def data_received(self, data):
        # processing, average server side execution time is around 30ms
        sleep(0.030)
        self.transport.write(os.urandom(64))
```

The application runs on Debian 9.9 and is started via systemd

To "benchmark" I use this script:

```py
import os, socket

from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import time as timestamp

def foobar(i):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 60000))

    while True:
        ms = timestamp()*1000
        s.send(os.urandom(128))
        s.recv(1024*2)
        print(i, timestamp()*1000-ms)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    instances = 4
    with Pool(instances) as p:
        print(p.map(foobar, range(0, instances)))
```

Comment: I think we're going to need more information. Can you provide how you're running the application, how many workers, configurations, etc?

Comment: Please consider providing [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's close to impossible to guess what's wrong with application you can't see.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to copy over the code when creating the question

Comment: What does your code do for those 30ms, does it involve blocking code like in the posted example? If so, that would explain the degradation of performance; you need to either switch to non-blocking calls or use tools like [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) to execute blocking or CPU-bound code.

Comment: It depends on type of request. The request I am most concerned about (the 30ms one) does a combination of database lookups and updates a few records afterwards. 

I considered `ProcessPoolExecutor` already but that would require me to initiate a new database connection for each process (MongoDB) which would cause a decent overhead.

Comment: If your database lookups are blocking (they're not `async def` and you don't use `await`), you definitely need to use `run_in_executor` to run them. You don't need a `ProcessPoolExecutor`, just pass None for the executor to use the default thread-pool executor of the event loop.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. With an increase of simultaneous connections and high request frequency the performance is still heavily degrading though. 

I now went another route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question here. I went with a solution that spawned multiple instances which were listening on base_port + x and I put a nginx TCP loadbalancer in front of it.

The individual `TCPServer` instances are still spawned as own process and communicate among themselves via a separate UDP connection and with the main process via `multiprocessing.Queue`.

While this does not "fix" the problem, it provides a somewhat scalable solution for my very specific problem.